# Can we use functions to compute coordinate X and Y in a tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to compute coords X and Y to build a figure  :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz} % pour dessins
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc, arrows} % pour complement tikz

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\focale{3}  
\def\angleg{32} 
\def\angled{90-\angleg} 

\coordinate (P1) at (\tan(\angleg)*\focale,1.5cm);
    ...
\end{tikzpicture}%<<<== must use well balanced curly-braces

\end{document}
```

but i have got an error :

```
Missing \endcsname inserted \coordinate (P1) at (\tan(32)
```

I tried to include the compute within `$` but :

```
Paragraph ended before \tikz@cc@parse@factor was complete
```

Comment: You just need braces, otherwise `Tikz` cannot recognize a calculation from a point `({tan(\angleg)*\focale},1.5cm)`.

Comment: many thanks and sorry...i have scanned some introductions notes to tikz, but i should have read in details...

Comment: Many thanks for all participations ! I think i will use answers linked to tikz, but pstricks seems to be quite interessant too. great tools ! and a great teams to support it ! - patrick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is: Yes, you can.

Your error is that you're typing the function with a backslash `\` which is the way to indicate to LaTeX that it's a command in the compilation. When calculating a number, functions shouldn't have a backslash, just `tan(angleg)` and so on.

For more complicated functions, use the curly bracket to indicate they are supposed to be together (as stated by @zeroth )`({tan(\angleg)*\focale},1.5cm)`.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the one statement of the reply about the \ (backslash) :

- the \tan must be replaced by 'tan' because you want the mathematical function to be aplied to the \angleg and not to write 'tan(58)'
- you must keep the '\angleg' because TeX has no idea about 'angleg ' (it's pure text)

I agree with the reply about the {} (curly brackets), which are mandatory each time you have some () in the point definition.

But the full answer would be to use the $ syntax to compute the point coordinates :

```
\coordinate (P1) at ($({tan(\angleg)*\focale},1.5cm)$);
```

Futhermore, it could be better practice to replace

```
\def\gnat{<some math expresion>}
```

by

```
\pfgmathsetmacro{\gnat}{<some math expresion>}
```

because the calculation is then parsed and performed immediatly when using the latter.

Comment: You're right about the backslash in `\angleg`, but it's not necessary to use the `$` syntax from the `calc` library if you're only evaluating a mathematical expression in a coordinate component. The `calc` library is only necessary when you're performing calculations that use full coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

With PSTricks. Just for comparison purposes.

PSTricks equivalent for TikZ `({tan(\complement)*\radius},1.5)` is

- `(+{Tan(\complement)*\radius},1.5)`
- `(**{Tan(\complement)*\radius} 1.5)`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\def\radius{3}  
\def\angle{45} 
\def\complement{90-\angle}

\begin{document}    
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](6,3)
\pnode(+{Tan(\complement)*\radius},1.5){P1}
%\pnode(**{Tan(\complement)*\radius} 1.5){P1}
\pscircle*[linecolor=red](P1){2pt}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Miscellaneous

In PSTricks, there are some ways to define a coordinate. It can be expressed in terms of existing nodes or mathematics expressions. With mathematics expression, we have 4 methods as follows.

- RPN for both abscissa and ordinate.

  For example: `(!2 3 mul 1 sub 2 0 add)` is a point `(5,2)`.
- RPN for  abscissa and algebraic for ordinate. The ordinate can be a function of `x`.

  For example: `(*{2 3 add} {x-3})` is a point `(5,2)`.
- Algebraic for abscissa and RPN for ordinate. The abscissa can be a function of `y`.

  For example: `(**{y*3-1} {1 1 add})` is a point `(5,2)`.
- Algebraic for both abscissa and ordinate.

  For example: `(+{3+2},1+1)` is a point  `(5,2)`.

The following example uses `\def` to express algebraic expression as a function of `x`, `y` or a constant.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
    \def\f[#1]{2*#1-1}

\begin{document}    
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,3)
    \pscircle*[linecolor=red](+{\f[2],\f[1]}){2pt}% its center is (3,1)
    \pscircle*[linecolor=green](*{1 0 add} {\f[x]}){2pt}% its center is (1,1)
    \pscircle*[linecolor=blue](**{\f[y]} {2 0 add}){2pt}% its center is (3,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the difference between the `+` syntax and the `**` syntax (apart from the fact that one needs a comma between the components, and the other doesn't)?

Comment: @Jake: I will update my answer to accommodate more general cases.